# Wordpress set featured image of first image from post

Tags: wordpress, action, thumbnails

I have tried every solution from similar answers and nothing seems to work on Wordpress 5.0 +

When saving a post I want to set its featured image to the first image in the post content.

```
function auto_set_featured( $post_id, $post, $update ) {
  $images = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent'    => $post_id,
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
  ) );

  set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $images[0]->ID );
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'auto_set_featured', 10, 3);
```

In `set_post_thumbnail()` if I set the image id manually it works but it does not seem to pick up `$images[0]->ID` I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

Note: I'm testing on posts which have multiple images in the content so `$images` should be returning an array. I also tried using `$post->ID` and `get_the_ID()` in the query and it does not work. I also tried adding the post ID manually for `post_parent`

Comment: How do you need that image in content, as a part of the content? Or its just shows before starting the content? Can you please more clear on "First Image"

Answer (score -2):

It is simple.In wordpress 5.0+,there is a gutenberg editor,so simply add image from editor same as featured image.It's working fine. i recently work like this.

Comment: This answer is unrelated, please remove